# android direction and alignment of drawtext

Tags: android, image, alignment, direction, drawtext

I'm writing an android program that writes some text on image using "drawtext" method of "Canvas" class.

So i want to set **alignment** and **direction** of the text because my text is in Persian language

In order to set the alignment of the text i have used "paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT)" method but i can't find any method or something else to set **direction** of text to right to left

In other words i want to use something like in "TextView" class : "setTextDirection(int)"

here is my code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(typeFace);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
int fontSize = 30;
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
canvas.drawText(textToWrite, bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight() - fontSize , paint);
```

Sorry for poor English 
Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection

Comment: I am sorry but does it matter when you are drawing the text instead of entering it in text box or something like that.

Comment: i want to set the direction of writing text